# z-index not working with image and p tag

Tags: html, css

i have an image and a  paragraph on a html page.

the code is as follows:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img
{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
background-color:red;
z-index:1;
}

p
{
z-index:2;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<img src="w3css.gif" width="100" height="140" />
<p>This is a sample paragraph for z-index testing</p>
</body>
</html>
```

here when is put z-index for image lesser than p tag then also it appears above p tag.

can anyone tell me why z-index in not working in my case???
thanks in advance

Comment: Please create a fiddle

Comment: Here is one : http://jsfiddle.net/wdezbuqr/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

assign `position: relative` to `<p>` for z-index to work.

For OP's Clarification :

from : [Any weird rules about z-index I should know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731716/any-weird-rules-about-z-index-i-should-know-about)

In addition, a child can never be below its parent. [This example](http://dabblet.com/gist/2048472), also on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Du8Qf/) illustrates it.

Based on the example you added it's clear the trouble you're having:

`z-index` is only relative to its parent, which in most cases is the document itself. If the `z-index` of one sibling is lower than another, nothing you change about first sibling's children can move it above its parents sibling. Read more about [stacking context](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=stacking%20context&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) if you're interested.

Here is a visual:

[image: z-index example]

Crossed out in red is what you want to do, and it is not possible with CSS (considering those small boxes are children of the bigger box, with markup which might look like this:

```
<div class="one">
</div>
<div class="two">
     <div> I can never be above "one", if my parent "two" isn't. </div>
</div>
```

A solution would be to move the "overlay" inside the wall, or better yet use a pseudo element (which is rendered as a child of the element it is applied to), because the overlay sounds like it something presentational, and thus should remain in the domain of CSS if an overlay div would add no semantic meaning.

Comment: thanks for your answer one more thing i wanted to ask why in this below link red color div is not appearing above all?http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/HTML_CSS/CSS/CSS_Selector/Use_z_index_and_child_selector_in_HTML_and_CSS.htm

Comment: position is set to absolute but

Answer (score 4):

`z-index` will work only if `position` property is specified,

so specify  `position: relative` for the `p` tag

```
p
{
position: relative;
z-index:2;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sajadlfc/0ck0vdaL/)

Answer (score 2):

Your `p` tag needs a `position` value too, so the `z-index` can affect him. 
But in this case you can asign `float:left` to the image, and place it inside the p tag so the paragraph text will wrap next to the image.

Answer (score 0):

change z-index to -1 for your image

`img
{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
background-color:red;
z-index: -1;
}`

Answer (score 0):

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

In your code, the p tag has a stack order of 2, whereas your img tag has a stack order of 1. Your p tag thus has a greater stack order, meaning the text will be shown in front of the image.

If you want the opposite result, try using negative values for both the image and the paragraph.

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 45px;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

See if the above snippet helps you.